# Error: "tag does not exist" when using maven release:perform to push container to ACR in bitbucket pipelines

Tags: java, maven, quarkus, bitbucket-pipelines, azure-container-registry

I have used Quarkus and bitbucket pipelines for more than 2 years and it normally functions very well. From Quarkus version 2.15 I got a problem when pushing the tag/container to Azure Container Registry. The error is:

```
 [io.quarkus.deployment.util.ExecUtil] tag does not exist: my-company.azurecr.io/my-app:1.2.30
```

The only difference from when it functions is that the Quarkus version is 2.15 and 2.16.

Here is the pipeline:

```
image: maven:3.8.7
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          size: 2x
          name: Build and Deploy Artifacts
          caches:
            - maven
            - docker
          services:
            - docker
          script:
            - git config --global user.email "pipeline@bitbucket.com"
            - git config --global user.name "Bitbucket Pipeline"
            - git remote set-url origin ${BITBUCKET_GIT_SSH_ORIGIN}

            - docker login my-company.azurecr.io -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID --password $AZURE_SECRET

            - mvn -B -DdryRun=true release:prepare -Dbitbucket.url=${BITBUCKET_GIT_SSH_ORIGIN}
            - mvn -B release:clean release:prepare -Dbitbucket.url=${BITBUCKET_GIT_SSH_ORIGIN} -DscmCommentPrefix="[skip ci] " -Darguments="-Dmaven.test.skip=true"
            - mvn -B release:perform -Dbitbucket.url=${BITBUCKET_GIT_SSH_ORIGIN} -DscmCommentPrefix="[skip ci] " -Darguments="-Dmaven.deploy.skip=true -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true -Dquarkus.container-image.push=true -Dquarkus.native.native-image-xmx=4g -Dquarkus.container-image.additional-tags=latest"
            - git status
            - git push

definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 7100
```

Stack trace:

```
[INFO] [INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.util.ExecUtil] tag does not exist: my-company.azurecr.io/my-app:1.2.30
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time:  04:50 min
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2023-01-26T10:43:00Z
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.16.0.Final:build (default) on project integration-experian: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[INFO] [ERROR]  [error]: Build step io.quarkus.container.image.docker.deployment.DockerProcessor#dockerBuildFromNativeImage threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Execution of 'docker push $ACR_HELM_REPOinsight.azurecr.io/si-integration-experian:1.2.30' failed. See docker output for more details
[INFO] [ERROR]  at io.quarkus.container.image.docker.deployment.DockerProcessor.dockerException(DockerProcessor.java:338)
[INFO] [ERROR]  at io.quarkus.container.image.docker.deployment.DockerProcessor.pushImage(DockerProcessor.java:331)
[INFO] [ERROR]  at io.quarkus.container.image.docker.deployment.DockerProcessor.lambda$createContainerImage$3(DockerProcessor.java:229)
[INFO] [ERROR]  at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$StreamBuilderImpl.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:411)
[INFO] [ERROR]  at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
[INFO] [ERROR]  at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
[INFO] [ERROR]  at io.quarkus.container.image.docker.deployment.DockerProcessor.createContainerImage(DockerProcessor.java:229)
[INFO] [ERROR]  at io.quarkus.container.image.docker.deployment.DockerProcessor.dockerBuildFromNativeImage(DockerProcessor.java:153)
[INFO] [ERROR]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO] [ERROR]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[INFO] [ERROR]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO] [ERROR]  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[INFO] [ERROR]  at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:909)
[INFO] [ERROR]  at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:281)
[INFO] [ERROR]  at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
[INFO] [ERROR]  at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
[INFO] [ERROR]  at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
[INFO] [ERROR]  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[INFO] [ERROR]  at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
[INFO] [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[INFO] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[INFO] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I just tried to build the Quarkus app using bitbucket pipeline and push it to ACR.